# Loading form with objects from an array

Tags: javascript

I need to store form data into an array of objects as a link. Then be able to click the link and fill the form with the objects/data to update or delete.

I'm able to store the form data as objects in an array, but can't figure out how to load it back into the form to update.

Now my selector function grabs the object but I just don't know how to load it into the form to update and delete. I've been stuck on this for a few weeks.

```
var selectActor = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var rowClicked = $(this).parent().parent();
    row = rowClicked.index();
    alert (actors[row].fName + " " + actors[row].lName + " " +    actors[row].gender + " " + actors[row].birthDate + " " + actors[row].action + " " + actors[row].comedy + " " + actors[row].drama + " " + actors[row].suspense + " " + actors[row].sciencefiction + " " + actors[row].horror);
    console.log(actors[row]);
};
```

Here is what I have in action so far. When I check console everything is correct with storing, and selecting, but I can't find anything that shows how to store objects into their respected form fields.

[Example in action](http://codepen.io/zzzian/pen/oxmzOE)

Comment: See my answer on your other question